# Create PHP Variables dynamically in foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am just trying to create PHP variables dynamically. below is the code I have tried.

```
    if($BrickTerritorys)
    {
            foreach($BrickTerritorys as $index=>$BrickTerritory)
            {
                ${"$T.$index"}= $BrickTerritory->TerritoryID;
                ${"'Weightage'.$index"} = $BrickTerritory->Weightage;
            }
            echo $T1."-".$T2."--".$Weightage1."---".$Weightage2; exit;
    }

while 
$BrickTerritorys is 
 [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 119
            [TerritoryID] => HYD-2-CMD
            [BrickCode] => 16
            [BrickName] => BUHURO
            [Weightage] => 40.00
            [BPCode] => bp00066
            [GroupCode] => CMD
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 36330
            [TerritoryID] => HYD-1-CMD
            [BrickCode] => 16
            [BrickName] => BUHURO
            [Weightage] => 60.00
            [BPCode] => bp00066
            [GroupCode] => CMD
        )
```

When I print in the last, nothing gets printed. Any help is much appreciated, please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what does var_dump($GLOBALS); says?

Comment: Using variable variables is _usually_ an indication of inappropriate array data storage.  You are adding unnecessary convolution to your code.

Comment: ["'T'.1"]=>
  string(9) "HYD-2-CMD"
  ["'Weightage'.1"]=>
  string(5) "40.00"
  ["'T'.2"]=>
  string(9) "HYD-1-CMD"
  ["'Weightage'.2"]=>
  string(5) "60.00"

result of Global variable... but still i didnt get my desired results..any help ??

Comment: You are performing dynamic variable generation via a loop, but then hardcoding (expecting) just two values from two rows.  Do you actually need variable variables?

Comment: @Salman do you realize that you have granted the green tick to an incorrect answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${"T$index"}` as well as `${"Weightage$index"}`

you don't need the dot,or you can use `${'T' . $index}`.  look at the dot. it's not addition operation while it in "". following this code:

```
if($BrickTerritorys)
{
    foreach($BrickTerritorys as $index=>$BrickTerritory)
    {
        ${"$T.$index"}= $BrickTerritory->TerritoryID;
        ${"'Weightage'.$index"} = $BrickTerritory->Weightage;
    }
    echo $T1."-".$T2."--".$Weightage1."---".$Weightage2; exit;
}
```

Comment: Your 1 point is wrong, it start from 1 and clearly mentioned in question detail. and your second point is absolutely OK, i it working now . Thumb up for you (y)

Comment: I don't like the quoting in this answer.  I feel this answer is incorrect.  Is this tested?

Comment: @Salman this answer is no good.  It only produces Notices and not the correct output.  Totally wrong.  Proof: https://3v4l.org/YEejB  Please rethink your green tick for the good of this community.

Comment: Who keeps upvoting this incorrect answer?  This will DEFINITELY mislead/confuse researchers.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing those lines like this:

```
        ${"T$index"}= $BrickTerritory->TerritoryID;
        ${"Weightage$index"} = $BrickTerritory->Weightage;
```

In your code `${"$T.$index"}` $T is searching for variable, and you should get undefined variable $T, so you have to remove $ sign, if you want to have T1, T2 variables.

After that, `${"'Weightage'.$index"}`, the apostrophes between Weightage means your variable will look like 'Weightage'.1, 'Weightage'.2.. and etc.

Comment: @Salman This answer DOES provide the desired output WITHOUT Notices.  Proof: https://3v4l.org/i0rVo

Answer (score 1):

This can be done a few different ways without variable variables AND produce a completely dynamic outcome.

Here's one: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YhD8A))

```
$array = (array)$BrickTerritorys;             // cast as array
$tids = array_column($array, 'TerritoryID');  // isolate column data
$was = array_column($array, 'Weightage');     // isolate column data
$merged = array_merge($tids, $was);           // add 2nd array data after 1st array data
foreach ($merged as $i => $v) {
    echo str_repeat('-', $i) , $v;            // increase hyphens on each iteration starting from 0
}
```

Output: (notice, no hardcoded echo)

```
HYD-2-CMD-HYD-1-CMD--40.00---60.00
```